# Foggy wind shield

Tags: hyundai, windshield

I own a Hyundai i10 Sportz Grand (India). For some reason my frontside windshield appears foggy with some weird spots in them. This is especially problematic when I drive at night or when it rains the light coming from vehicles from opposite side scatters all over the screen and I can't see anything. Many a time I just stop the car, I am not sure what's causing this, Hyundai service center is unable to help. Any pointers would be really helpful

[image: Night view through windscreen showing flare from marks on glass]

Comment: I've had something similar when the inside of my windshield got greasy, this can happen over time. Have you tried cleaning it with window cleaner? It may take a few repeated cleanings if it is really bad.

Answer (score 3):

If you stick a short length of tape on the inside and outside of the glass, then examine the glass from the inside and outside, do the spots appear to be in the middle of the thickness of the glass?

For safety reason, windshield glass is now generally made of laminated glass.  There is a layer of plastic bonded between two layers of glass.  If the bonding fails and the glass and plastic separate you will get a cloudy effect.

If this is the issue, the only way to fix this would be to replace the windsheild.

If the spots are on the very outside or inside of the glass, then this will not be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be as Howie suggests with delamination of the windshield. The alternative if that is not the case is, you have some sort of residue on the windshield, which could be on the inside or the outside.

If not delaminating, you need to figure out where the fogging is occurring. Usually in circumstances as you describe, the fogging is actually happening on the inside of the windshield. It should be easily discerned where the spots are at, but if you're feeling really froggy, just clean both inside and out thoroughly and you'll be golden.

If this is the case, you need to use ***good*** window cleaner as well as a superior cleaning cloth and some elbow grease to get rid of them. A superior cleaning cloth may be on made of microfiber. Use two rags: one for initial cleaning and a second for final buffing. I've found foaming glass cleaner to be far superior to the like of Windex or other "blue" kinds of window cleaner. They are far less likely to leave  streaking or residue behind and clean well with minimal effort.